# Is there a max time limit for Tomcat to expect a response back from a page?

Tags: java, tomcat, timeout

I have a web form that onsubmit reads the form entries, and then calls a .jsp that does a lot of processing, saving rows to a database, before returning to the original form. This processing typically takes about 75 seconds.

I am finding that sometimes the saved number of rows in the database is as expected, and sometimes it is short.

Tomcat is being used as the web server. Does tomcat have a time-out configuration parameter, that governs how long a page can take before getting a response?

Thanks

Comment: Your title is back to front. Tomcat doesn't get 'responses back from pages', it *sends* responses *as* pages. What you really seem to be asking is about time limits on *request processing.*

Answer (score 0):

Probably the timeout is on the database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following page from Tomcat 7 documentation:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

The attributes for your interest include:

1. asyncTimeout
2. connectionTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
The problem I was experiencing turned out to be the connection pool I was using in the called jsp.  I learnt (when he came back from holiday)  that the developer who produced the connection pool software library had introduced a 60 second time limit .. something to do with preventing database connection leaks.
Sorry to send you on a wild goose chase!